# The problem that the internal data of v-data-table is displayed as a single line

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm making a simple v-data-table (vue2 with vuetify). Most of the internal column data size is short(5~20 bytes), but one column is over 500 bytes.

I thought that defining the header width would set it to multi-line, but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem

The screen looks like this:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________
|header 1  | header2                                           | header 3| header4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| sdfsdfsdf| this is problem sososososososo long long long long|   1234   | 567567 |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=> i want multiline
__________________________________________________________________
|header 1  | header2                         | header 3| header4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| sdfsdfsdf| this is problem sosos           |   1234   | 567867 |
           |  ososososo long long long long  |          |        |  
------------------------------------------------------------------

<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="checksumList" class="elevation-1" fixed-header width="300px" height="685px">

  headers: [
    { text: 'id', value: 'id', sortable: false },
    { text: 'name', value: 'name', sortable: false },
    { text: 'hash', value: 'hash', sortable: false, width : "20px" },
    { text: 'display_name', value: 'display_name', sortable: false, width : "20px"},
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vuetify 2.6.0+, you could define cell class directly in `headers` array.
It will be applied then for each `<td>` tag in one column.

This way, by example:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
/>
...
data () {
  return {
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
        cellClass: 'width-400'
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      ...
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        ...
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich with a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long name',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
...
<style>
.width-400 {
  width: 400px
}
</style>
```

Test this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/jOGRWKy)

Comment: thank you. I upgraded to vuetify 2.6.2 this time, but I got the following error.

Comment: <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="checksumList"
              class="elevation-1"
              overflow
              single-expand
              height="685px">

Comment: headers: [
        { text: 'header1', value: 'hashIndex', sortable: false},
        { text: 'header2', value: 'hashItems', sortable: false, width:"400px"},
      ],

Comment: It is still displayed as a single line. Changed vuetify/sass/sass loader version. Do you need anything else?

Comment: @worldstar, you should create your own CSS class and define `cellClass` attribute in headers array with yours created CSS class. I have provided an example in my answer

Comment: { text: 'header', value: 'long~~ something', sortable: false, cellClass: 'width-400' } <style scoped>
.width-400 {
  width: 400px
  }
</style> What am I missing? both don't work If the data is short, the header size seems to be adjusted normally. It does not work as the data becomes larger than the width.

Comment: @worldstar try to remove `scoped`